# How do you integrate $\int _{0}^t\:\dot p(s) p(s) + p^2(s)ds$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Given $p(s)$ some single valued function

How can I show that $$\int _{0}^t\:\dot p(s) p(s) + p^2(s)ds$$ has resulting in something along the line of $$\frac{p^2(s)}{2}$$

note $\dot p(s)$ signifies derivative against time

Answer (score 1):

$$\int _{0}^t\:\dot p(s) p(s) + p^2(s)ds = \int_{p(0)}^{p(t)} p\, dp + \int  _{0}^tp^2(s)ds = \frac12\left(p^2(t) - p^2(0)\right) + \int_{0}^tp^2(s)ds $$

Comment: How was the substitution done in the first term of the second equality?

Comment: @IllegalImmigrant,   an antiderivative of $\int \frac{dp}{dt} p \,dt $ is $\frac 12 p^2$